# Compilation Error when passing multiple arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, arguments, repeater

The problem I'm having, is that I need to pass in multiple arguments through a button click. I have a repeater object that prints out values from a sqlquery, and the button has arguments that are from that same query

Here is My Repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Edit_Repeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="Edit_Repeater_Source">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="u_Repeater">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Group Name:
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Permission Level:
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Remove:
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Group_Name")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="Submit_Remove" runat="server" Text="Remove Permission" OnClick="Remove_Permission" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("GID") + ";" + Eval("PID") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
protected void Remove_Permission(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arg = new string[2];            
        string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
        float GID = float.Parse(arg[0]);
        float PID = float.Parse(arg[1]);
        string UID = User_ID.SelectedValue;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["app_migrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Membership WHERE GID = @GID AND PID = @PID AND UID = @UID", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GID", SqlDbType.BigInt, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@GID"].Value = GID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PID", SqlDbType.BigInt, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@PID"].Value = PID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@UID"].Value = UID;

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting no build errors, but when I run the page I get a Compilation Error saying:

No overload for 'Remove_Permission' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

I'm almost positive the code is right, so what is the problem?

Comment: Hi Joel, this is more of a comment than an answer but, you should be using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GID", SqlDbType.BigInt, -1);`.  Also, can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `CommandEventArgs` to [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.eventargs.aspx) - then cast your sender to Button and get the command argument from there.

```
protected void Remove_Permission(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button !=null)
    {
        var commandArg = button.CommandArgument;
        //etc....
    }
}
```

Or use the [Command Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx) instead of the `Click` event.

Comment: Changing it to OnCommand worked. Thank you for the easiest and efficient fix

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your Remove_Permission function should be of type:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(
Object sender,
EventArgs e
)
```